# Telling qmake to compile dependency lib

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a main pro file for my application and I would like to tell qmake to also compile a separate lib at the same time as the application. The lib also has a pro file in its directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Put the lib and the app in separate subdirectories and make your top-level .pro file to use the `SUBDIRS` template:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = lib app
app.depends = lib
```

Comment: or CONFIG += ordered to compile the subdirs in the order they are listed in SUBDIRS.